# Media query not working as expected on iPad Pro

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

I've got my visitor portal setup for 3 types of devices: mobile (less than 800px width), low-res desktop and hi-res desktop, like this:

```
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-height: 899px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (min-height: 900px)" href="..." type="text/css">   
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

All this works rather well but with the iPad Pro portrait, the width of the screen is less than 800px but the stylesheet that's selected is the low-res desktop. What do I need to change to make it work?

Edit (to clarify the problem)

When I do something like this

```
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-height: 899px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (min-height: 900px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media ="only screen and (max-width: 800px),
only screen and (max-device-width:1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.1) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (max-device-height:1366px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.1) and (orientation:landscape)"
href="..." rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The problem is that the styles get mixed-up at different resolutions. I'm looking to make it work so that only one stylesheet is active at anytime.

Comment: Have you specified the viewport size?

Comment: @MunimMunna: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: you can use [https://mydevice.io/](https://mydevice.io/) to see what width the ipad is displaying.

Comment: You are using the viewport `meta` tag. 
Just to clarify, the `physical size` is not the same as the `CSS size`.
Apple iPad Pro 9.7 CSS size is : 768 - 1024px
Apple iPad Pro: 1024 - 1366px
Source: https://mydevice.io/devices/

Can you create a live example or provide the address?

Which CSS file should be active on Ipad Pro, the second one(low-res desktop)?

Answer (score 4):

**iPad Media Queries**

**iPad Media Queries (All generations - including iPad mini)**

**iPad in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPad in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPad in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

To know more about device media queries, please visit [Stephen.io/mediaqueries](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)
Source credits to http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Hope this may help you.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

So, if i were you, I will do something like this:

```html
<!-- small devices non-retina (apple use 2x for ipads and 3x for the newest iphones) -->
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- small devices retina (apple use 2x and 3x) -->
<link 
  media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 800px),
         only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 800px),
         only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 800px),
         only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 800px),
         only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 800px),
         only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 800px)" 
   href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- bigger devices low-res -->
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-height: 899px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- bigger devices higher res -->
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (min-height: 900px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If you see in this article of CSS Tricks: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) you can go very specific trying to point each devices. Or get use of some of this examples (maybe in combination with `orientation: portrait`)

Lastly I'll like to say that, personally, I only use the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` or `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3` to point to the high-res raster/bitmap images (jpg and png) I'll use.

I hope this help.

---

You can find more info about 2x and 3x devices and how this affects images on this article from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/).

Other resources:

- [MDN Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
- Already mentioned by another answer (CSS Tricks): [Retina Display Media Query](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).
- Already mentioned by myself, also CSS Tricks: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)
- A comparative of devices and screens: [A quick reference for iOS devices](http://iosres.com/)

More official sources:

- [W3C Recommendation 19 June 2012 - Media Queries - Resolution](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution)
- [Apple's Safari Web Content Guide - Optimizing Web Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html)
- Android's [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Tried this in the Chrome emulator, doesn't work, just uses the hi-res file. Will go try it in a native iPad pro.

Comment: you could use the xcode simulator also: developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/…. And you'll have to see which of the ipad's are you using (to point the right values on max-width). As I said, you'll like to see the article of [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). Specific for Portrait, its say: _Declare the same value for min- and max-width to avoid colliding with desktops_ [Source](https://medium.com/connect-the-dots/css-media-queries-for-ipad-pro-8cad10e17106)

Answer (score 0):

iPad pro has a retina display, with a pixel aspect ratio of probably 2, which makes virtually 2 x 800 = 1600 pixels. That's why the selected media query is the wrong one. You'll have to deal with pixel aspect ratio too. See this : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Answer (score 0):

This Query working on all device I hope your issue is resolve.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .big-dot{
      width:280px; height:280px; margin:0 auto; background:red;
    }

}/*===========Mobile Device=============*/


@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1280px){
    .big-dot{
      width:280px; height:280px; margin:0 auto; background:green;
    }

}/*===========Tab and  IPad Pro Device=============*/



@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    .big-dot{
      width:280px; height:280px; margin:0 auto; background:cyan;
    }

}/*===========Large Desktop  Device=============*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="big-dot">
    Time Big Dot /.....
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>`? I find including this makes retina devices behave as expected without any extra fiddling with 2x and 3x devices mentioned by f-spin

edit: just beware, you may find this affects layout that currently works well, but overall should make media queries more predictable once you've got over that (probably quite small) hump

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge resolution of iPad Pro is (1024x1366)px and iPad Pro9.7 is (768x1024)px. So if you want to load specific stylesheet for specific resolution, then you might be load the stylesheet of

```
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)" href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

***This Query working on all device I hope your issue is resolve.***

```
  /*---------------------------------------------------------------------
        Large Desktops
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

    }


    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------
        Desktops
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {


    }


    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------
        Tablets Devices
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {



    }


    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
       Mobile Devices
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px) {

    }


    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Small Screen Mobile Devices
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px) {

    }
```